# Git server for Windows

Tags: git

I am new to Git.

Is the installation for Git server same as how we install on local machine?

I am finding a GUI Git installer for server, I found one http://gitstack.com/, but is there a any open source one?

Comment: there is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566537/easiest-way-to-set-up-a-git-https-server-on-windows you can use that approach.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at http://gitblit.com/ or http://www.scm-manager.org/ for platform independent Git servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I would not say that. Although there is a number of ways to share a git repo hosting a central server usually differs from it.

So beside using SSH connections to share a repository I went the Subversion approach using HTTP - it is in my Opinion the easiest way to access a repository without managing SSH keys. On Linux people may be more fit with that but not every developer has a talent for that.

So you could use Apache HTTPD and DAV to host a repository: http://techblog.zabuchy.net/2012/git-server-with-apache-authentication-on-ubuntudebian/
This is for Ubuntu but the modules are available on Windows too.
Most self-hosting solutions are based on Apache HTTPD and a module.
(But most of them are Linux focused, Windows is not that common for this)

There are products like Atlassian Stash http://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview that are even more comfortable.

But some people even integrate it into CollabNet: http://dylanbeattie.blogspot.ch/2011/02/how-to-host-git-in-same-apache-server.html

So with Apache HTTPD you should be able to build cost friendly solution.

Comment: Note that git over HTTP is quite crippled, it is better to set up SSH and use the native git protocol.